# Add custom js to UnderStrap

Tags: wordpress

Where shall I add my custom js file in Understrap (WP)?

js/

or

src/js/

Also, I assume then I need to load it from inc/enqueue.php and modify gulpfile.js to compile it.

Is this correct?

Comment: [this will help you](https://github.com/understrap/understrap/issues/47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the folder named "JS" which is included on Understrap theme.  However , you could  include your javascript files on any folder.

```html
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-site.js', array(), null, true );
```

Regards.

Answer (score 6):

For this purpose we add an empty js file to UnderStrap. Available since the latest 0.8.2 release.
You can find it in src/js/custom-javascript.js

It is part of the compiling gulp task "gulp scripts".
So you JS will be added to the minified theme.min.js at the end and you don´t have to enqueue an extra gile anymore.

If you keep the file empty nothing will be added to the theme.min.js.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  custom-javascript.js has benefits as mentioned in this post.  Work with the system, not against it.